# Asynchronous gathering of values using c++11 lambda

Tags: c++11, lambda

c++11 lambdas are a perfectly suited for callbacks like this:

```
// Event notification
onEvent([](){printf("Event fired\n");});
// async IO
get(key, [](int value){
  printf("%i\n", value);
});
```

But is there a simple/efficient way to gather data without modifying the interface of get()?

```
auto cb = [](int value1, int value2) {
  printf("%i\n", value1);
  printf("%i\n", value2);
};
get(key1, cb);
get(key2, cb);
```

So when I only get notified when both events happened?

Comment: Why would you want that interface?  Magic dependencies between multiple calls seems icky.  `get( key1, key2, cb )` makes it far clearer to me, or `get( keys(key1, key2), cb )` even.

Comment: imagine you want to mix with many different interfaces, like wait for resource a and event b or something like this.

Comment: But your design still involves creating magic dependencies between distinct parts of code.  Magic dependencies make code very difficult to understand, and require explicit state behind the scenes of possibly unbounded complexity.  Sure, you know that you intend to call the n methods with your lambda in a row, tightly together: but that isn't what your design says will happen.  `get(key1, cb);` then a few billion instructions and few hours of time pass, then `get(key2, cb);`, and then it happens is what you are actually asking to work.  Think how silly that is?

Comment: If you need to calculate the sum of key1 + key2 then there's no other way to do it even if it takes hours?  Whats silly about that ?